# Finding time zone of Ireland using TimeZoneInfo object

Tags: c#

I need to get the TimeZoneInfo of (IST) Irish Standard Time. I executed the following statement but ended in an exception. What am i doing wrong here?

```
TimeZoneInfo tmz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Ireland Standard Time");
```

The exception says

> The time zone ID 'Ireland Standard Time' was not found on the local
>   computer.

Comment: The exception doesn't match your code. "Irish" <-> "Ireland". So what is your real code or the real exception message?

Comment: Well then... Try the correct name: "Irish Standard Time". But at least on my machine, it isn't found either. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx), the list of timezones in the registry is not complete.

Comment: I believe you should be looking for `western europe standard time` which is where ireland falls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any such time zone.

You can get the time zones using the `GetSystemTimeZones` method. I used this code:

```
foreach (var zone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0:00.00} {1}", zone.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours, zone.Id);
}
```

In the middle of the list are the time zones that you might be interrested in:

```
...
-01,00 Azores Standard Time
-01,00 Cape Verde Standard Time
00,00 Morocco Standard Time
00,00 UTC
00,00 GMT Standard Time
00,00 Greenwich Standard Time
01,00 W. Europe Standard Time
01,00 Central Europe Standard Time
01,00 Romance Standard Time
01,00 Central European Standard Time
01,00 W. Central Africa Standard Time
01,00 Namibia Standard Time
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Timezone Id for Ireland is "GMT Standard Time". This one works for me with `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` one Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you get a **TimeZoneNotFoundException**

> The time zone identifier specified by id was not found. This means
>   that a registry key whose name matches id does not exist, or that the
>   key exists but does not contain any time zone data.

[Link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx)

The registry key which is used is:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time
>   Zones

Answer (score 1):

The list of timezones supported by `TimeZoneInfo` is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`. My copy of Windows 7 doesn't have any information for Ireland.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN :

> FindSystemTimeZoneById tries to match id to the subkey names of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones

On my local pc (windows 7) I don't found the ID "Irish Standard Time"

[MSDN TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

example copied from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

run it to see what timezone id's you can use:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
Console.WriteLine("The local system has the following {0} time zones", zones.Count);
foreach (TimeZoneInfo zone in zones)
   Console.WriteLine(zone.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find this solution in VB.NET.  Thanks to the code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397784(v=vs.110).aspx, I've worked out a solution.  Hopefully this will get you to the point where you just need a good VB.NET to C# converter to put an end to this 5-year-old issue.

```
Dim IST As TimeZoneInfo
' Declare necessary TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule objects for time zone
' delta is the amount of change during DST
Dim delta As New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)
Dim adjustment As TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule
Dim adjustmentList As New List(Of TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule)
' Declare transition time variables to hold transition time information
Dim transitionRuleStart, transitionRuleEnd As TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime

' Simplifying some elements for later use
Dim CurrTime As Date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
Dim EST As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")
Dim CST As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")
Dim UTC As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC")

' Define new Irish Standard Time zone at UTC, but with DST
transitionRuleStart = TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFloatingDateRule(#2:00:00 AM#, 3, 2, DayOfWeek.Sunday)
transitionRuleEnd = TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFloatingDateRule(#2:00:00 AM#, 11, 1, DayOfWeek.Sunday)
adjustment = TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.CreateAdjustmentRule(#1/1/2007#, Date.MaxValue.Date, delta, transitionRuleStart, transitionRuleEnd)
adjustmentList.Add(adjustment)

Dim adjustments(adjustmentList.Count - 1) As TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule
adjustmentList.CopyTo(adjustments)

IST = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("IST", New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), _
      "(GMT 00:00) Irish Standard Time (Ireland)", "Irish Standard Time", _
      "Irish Daylight Time", adjustments)

' Testing.
Debug.Print("Time in Ireland: " & TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(CurrTime, UTC, IST))
Debug.Print("Time in New York: " & TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(CurrTime, UTC, EST))
Debug.Print("Time in Chicago: " & TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(CurrTime, UTC, CST))
```